# Get sheet names in Excel95 workbook using OleDB

Tags: c#, excel, oledb

I am having trouble using the Jet provider and OleDb to get the sheet names in an Excel95 workbook.

I have a workbook with 3 sheets, Sheet1, Sheet2, Sheet3. I am using the following code to extract the sheet name:

```
var connectionString =
String.Format("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source={0};Extended Properties=\"Excel 8.0;HDR=YES;IMEX=1\"", filePath);

using (var connection = new OleDbConnection(connectionString))
{
    connection.Open();
    var dtXlsSchema = connection.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, null);        
}
```

This ends up returning a datatable with only one record in it, for Sheet1. I'm guessing there is something wrong with the connection string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OleDb will not be aware of empty sheets.

As long as the sheets have some data in them, you should get their names.

Comment: That is bizarre...the sheet exists in the workbook. That's like saying a table does not exist in a schema if it is empty. Oh well, thanks for the answer.

Comment: Excel and OleDb are not the same.  OleDb is only interested in sheets that actually have data.

Answer (score 2):

As per [this page](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/257819), use Excel 5.0 instead of Excel 8.0 in your connection string.

Does that help?

EDIT:

```
"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source={0};Extended Properties=\"Excel 5.0;HDR=YES;IMEX=1\"", filePath);
```

EDIT2:

> Excel Version: Specify Excel 5.0 for an Excel 95 workbook (version 7.0
>   of Excel), and Excel 8.0 for an Excel
>   97, Excel 2000, or Excel 2002 (XP)
>   workbook (versions 8.0, 9.0, and 10.0
>   of Excel).